# Atualização automática do model relacionado através da FK - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Estou tentando usar o signal para fazer um update de subtração em uma tabela baseada no valor que o usuário selecionar. uma situação de exemplo: 
Na tabela `Materiais` tenho o material caneta com os campos: `codigo_material`, `descricao_material` e `quantidade_estoque`.

na tabela `Materiais_Solicitacao` pego o material através de uma `ForeignKey` e também possuo o campo `quantidade_aprovada`.

Estou tentando fazer com que o valor passado no campo `quantidade_aprovada` seja subtraído de `quantidade_estoque`.

models.py  Materiais

```
class Materiais(models.Model):
    descricao_material = models.CharField('Descrição do Material', max_length=100)
    codigo_material = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    almoxarifado_relacionamento = models.ForeignKey(Almoxarifado, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantidade_estoque = models.FloatField('Quantidade em Estoque', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Material'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Materiais'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao_material
```

models.py Materiais_solicitacao

```
Class Materiais_Solicitacao(models.Model):
        quantidade_material = models.FloatField('Quantidade de Material', null=False, blank=False)
        quantidade_aprovada = models.FloatField('Quantidade Aprovada', blank=True, null=True)
        relacionamento_materiais = models.ForeignKey(Materiais, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        relacionamento_solicitacao = models.ForeignKey(Solicitacao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        unidade_relacionamento = models.ForeignKey(Unidade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Material da Solicitação'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Material das Solicitações'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.relacionamento_materiais)
```

tentativa de signal que fiz

```
def update_estoque(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        materiais = instance.relacionamento_materiais.all()
        estoque_update = 0

        for x in materiais:

            estoque_update = x.quantidade_estoque - instance.quantidade_aprovada
            instance.quantidade_estoque = estoque_update
            print(estoque_update)  

        pre_save.connect(update_estoque, sender=Materiais)
```

views.py

```
class SolicitacaoCreateUpdate(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'administrativo_permissao'
    raise_exception = True
    model = Solicitacao
    template_name = 'administrativo/administrativo_update.html'
    form_class = SolicitacaoForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SolicitacaoCreateUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['materiaisList'] = Materiais_Solicitacao.objects.all().filter(relacionamento_solicitacao_id=self.object)
        context['materiaisEstoque'] = Materiais.objects.all()
        context['avisos'] = Aviso.objects.all()
        if self.request.POST:
            context['materiais'] = MateriaisFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['materiais'] = MateriaisFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        materiais = context['materiais']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if materiais.is_valid():
                materiais.instance = self.object
                materiais.save()
        return super(SolicitacaoCreateUpdate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detalheAdministrativo', args=(self.object.pk,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nao vejo a necessidade de utilizar Signals, aliás quando vejo alguem utilizando sempre lembro de uma frase: "[Signals é um podereso recurso que nunca deveria ser utilizado](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/)". Há várias maneiras de fazer o que vc deseja, vou fazer da forma mais proxima da sua abordagem (atualizacao pelo model). Para exemplificar criei 2 models, um chamado `Item` que representa os itens de estoque, com apenas 2 campos: `descricao` e `quantidade_atual` (seus nomes já são descritivos). E outro que representa as retiradas dos itens do estoque, com os campos: `item` que é uma FK relacionada ao model Item, `descricao` e `quantidade` que representa a quantidade a ser retirado do item do estoque.

Note que sobreponho o método `save` no model `Retirada` para subtrair o valor do campo `quantidade` (da "retirada" em curso) do campo `quantidade_atual` do item relacionado.

Criação dos models (app: Core):

```
from django.db import models

# For DRY
bnull = dict(blank=True, null=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField('Descrição do Material', max_length=100)
    quantidade_atual = models.FloatField('Quantidade em Estoque', **bnull)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao

class Retirada(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='Itens', on_delete=models.CASCADE, **bnull)
    descricao = models.CharField('Descricao', max_length=120, **bnull)
    quantidade = models.FloatField('Quantidade retirada', **bnull)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        # Salve os dados
        self.item.quantidade_atual -= self.quantidade
        self.item.save()
        super(Retirada, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```

Após a criação dos campos na app, vamos apenas fazer as migrations, não é preciso criar `views` e nem `templates` para a demonstracação de como funciona:

Migrations:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Após fazer as migrations vamos ao shell do django:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

Estando no shell do django vamos criar 3 itens de estoque, no banco.

```
>>> from core.models import Item, Retirada

# Criando 3 objetos do tipo Item
>>> Item.objects.create(descricao='Item 1',quantidade_atual=10)
>>> Item.objects.create(descricao='Item 2',quantidade_atual=10)
>>> Item.objects.create(descricao='Item 3',quantidade_atual=10)
```

Podemos agora listar os itens de estoque:

```
>>> for i in Item.objects.all():
        print(i.descricao, '|', i.quantidade_atual)
```

Saída:

```
Item 1 | 10.0
Item 2 | 10.0
Item 3 | 10.0
```

Vamos, agora, criar algumas retiradas dos Itens **Item 1** e **Item 2** de forma aleatória:

```
# Selecionando os itens
item1 = Item.objects.get(descricao='Item 1')
item2 = Item.objects.get(descricao='Item 2')

# Criando as retiradas:
Retirada.objects.create(item=item1, descricao='Retirada 1 Item 1', quantidade=4)
Retirada.objects.create(item=item2, descricao='Retirada 1 Item 2', quantidade=2)
Retirada.objects.create(item=item1, descricao='Retirada 2 Item 1', quantidade=)
Retirada.objects.create(item=item2, descricao='Retirada 2 Item 2', quantidade=4)
Retirada.objects.create(item=item1, descricao='Retirada 3 Item 1', quantidade=1)
Retirada.objects.create(item=item1, descricao='Retirada 1 Item 1', quantidade=1)
```

Agora vamos listar todas as retiradas e as quantidades atuais de cada item utilizando somente o model `Retirada`:

```
print('Descricao         | Qt  | Atual','-'*31, sep='\n') 
for r in Retirada.objects.all():
    print(r.descricao, '|', r.quantidade, '|', r.item.quantidade_atual)
```

Saida:

```
Descricao         | Qt  | Atual
-------------------------------
Retirada 1 Item 1 | 4.0 | 1.0
Retirada 1 Item 2 | 2.0 | 4.0
Retirada 2 Item 1 | 3.0 | 1.0
Retirada 2 Item 2 | 4.0 | 4.0
Retirada 3 Item 1 | 1.0 | 1.0
Retirada 1 Item 1 | 1.0 | 1.0
```

**Conclusão:**
Voce não precisa utilizar Signals para fazer o que vc apresenta no codigo, pode fazer isso e muito mais sobrepondo o metodo `save` do model.

Se me permite vou fazer algumas observacoes sobre o seu código:

1. Voce esta misturando 2 estilos de codificação quando define uma classe, CamelCase e snake_case, a convenção para o django é a utilização de snake_case para a maior parte do codigo mas a definição de classes é CamelCase;
2. Voce pode criar o nome que quiser para uma campo FK, mas a convenção é utilizar o mesmo nome da classe relacionada (em minúsculo) por exemplo, ao invés de `relacionamento_materias` voce poderia utilizar, simplesmente `materiais`, tenha em mente que na sua app esse campo será um objeto instancia da classe a qual ele aponta (ou se relaciona);
3. Os nomes de classes devem ficar no singular (ao invés de `Materiais`, vc deveria usar `Material`), é certo que a maioria dos cursos nas faculdades e fora delas recomendam utilizar nomes de tabelas no plural, mas acredite, no Django e FW modernos isso acaba gerando problemas, Django ja tem uma forma de "pluralização" automática (ok, vc não é obrigado a usar, mas quebra um galhão no inicio do desenvolvimento).